# Creating own npm package vue.js and vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Hi I wanted to ask if someone can help me with this I am trying to create my own package to publish on `npm` so what I wanted is that to add vuetify on my package and install my own package to a project that is also using vuetify. Right now I am using `vue-sfc-rollup` and I have installed `vuetify` on my package but it seemed it doesnt work it gives me an error  `Unknown custom element: <v-form>` is it because I am using vuetify on both package and the project?

Comment: I'm also trying to do that, have you ever figured out the way?

Comment: what's your vue version? vue2 or vue3?